# How do I turn off url printing for html docs from R Markdown

Tags: r, markdown, pandoc

I created an .html document using R Markdown. Embedded links show up in parentheses when I print the document (ink and paper printing).

#### Input:

```
---
title: ''
author: ''
output: html_document
---

[Google](https://www.google.com/)
```

#### Printed output:

> Google (https://www.google.com/)

Is there a way to override this feature? Is this because of R Markdown, Markdown, or Pandoc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an R Markdown feature: the default CSS contains the equivalent of the following style definition, which causes this behavior:

```css
@media print{
  a[href]:after{
    content:" (" attr(href) ")"
  }
}
```

You can overwrite this with your own CSS, e.g.:

````
---
title: ''
author: ''
output: html_document
---

```{=html}
<style>
@media print{
  a[href]:after{
    content:""!important;
  }
}
</style>
```

[Google](https://www.google.com/)
````